# Trigger.io build error: Failed when running aapt.exe: android-platform.apk not found

Tags: trigger.io

I'm running trigger.io on my new machine (all works ok on my old one).

Each time I build I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed when running C:\AndroidSDK/build-tools\21.1.1\aapt.exe:     (skipping file '.do_not_use' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
>   ERROR: Asset package include 'C:\Users\MyUser\forge-workspace\test-app.lib\android-platform.apk' not found.

I've checked: that the file 'android-platform.apk' is available in the directory it is searching it in.

I've tried:

- re-install android sdk
- Deleting the 'android-platform.apk' file. It gets download again autom. but still gives the error
- created an new trigger.io app on the default location
- running trigger.io with admin privileges

Anyone any idea on what else could be causing the error?

Many thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my Question, in case anyone bumps into the same problem:

There have been some major issues with Google's recent v21.x release of their Android build-tools package that are responsible for this error.

The temporary workaround is to **uninstall** all versions of the Android SDK Build-tools later than v20.
After **installing** the **V20** version of the Android build tools everything works again.

*Note from trigger.io: We'll be releasing platform version v2.2.7 soon which will bring full support for v21.x of Google's tools.*